# How to go about implementing this calendar feature

Tags: python, django, calendar

I'm trying to make a calendar app that when you click through on a date, takes you to all the events for that particular date. I'm writing the app in Python/Django. A good example would be the event calendar in craigslist.

I'm not sure how I should go about implementing this. I'm not looking for exact solutions but more of a guideline or relevant material so I can figure it out myself.

I saw Django-swingtime and Django-agenda but they seemed over specified over my needs.

I also came across this http://journal.uggedal.com/creating-a-flexible-monthly-calendar-in-django/ but it's not step by step enough for my current level of understanding.

Is figuring out his code and using HTML Calendars the best way to go or are there other options?

Comment: Did you ever find how to use the code in mentioned link ? I am exactly where you were 8 years ago

Answer (score 0):

I guess your app is using database where you store all available events, right? Then you show calendar with date values. Then when you click some date, you just switch your presentation (view, page... whatever), connect to database and select all events that have same date as date from clicked element. Is this what are you asking for, or I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Yeah thats right! Your answer might be more suitable as a comment btw! ^_^

Comment: So what more do you want? I ponted you to rought guideline, I am not going to code it for you :)

Comment: Perhaps more details into generating the calendar and tying it to the database?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the Django ORM is helpful when it comes to queries involving dates. You may consider doing raw sql .